# When can we define the stalks of a sheaf?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

So i am reading rotman's book on homological algebra, and in it he states in Theorem 5.91, the following:
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{A}$ an abelian category and consider the category of sheaves over $X$ with values in $\mathcal{A}$: $Sh(X,\mathcal{A})$. Then $Sh(X,\mathcal{A})$ itself is also an abelian category.
And in the proof he uses the stalks $\mathcal{F}_x$ of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}\in Sh(X,\mathcal{A})$. Rotman initially defined stalks only for the case $\mathcal{A}=Ab$, the category of abelian groups, which is fine, as this is cocomplete.
But in general $\mathcal{A}$ is not cocomplete, and we only know of the existence of finite colimits.
So my question is can we nonetheless define $\mathcal{F}_x$? Or do we need to suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is cocomplete?

Comment: I guess the usual definition of a stalk *does* require your category $\cal{A}$ to have filtered colimits. Under suitable finiteness conditions on the topological space $X$ you might be able to get away with finite colimits, but I don't think this is what Rotman has in mind there. Are you sure, he doesn't require cocompleteness of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I wonder if it might be possible to come up with a counterexample if $\mathcal{A}$ is the category of finitely generated abelian groups.  There might be some quotient of sheaves where the usual construction of taking the pointwise quotient and then taking the sheafification would result in a sheaf whose sections are not finitely generated.  (Of course, you would still have to show that no other pointwise-finitely-generated sheaf can satisfy the required universal property for the quotient.)

Comment: Rotman is well-known for being full of mistakes (https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rotman/errhomalg.pdf), I think you can safely assume he only cares about the cocomplete case.